# React convert the component as pdf using jspdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, html-to-pdf

I am creating an  react generating pdf when user Click the button,I have five page html component, and I don't need show the component browser,I want to show in pdf only ,Please Help and searched lot but my bad luck ,any link,ideas it's usefull for me

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import Document from "./Doocument"


const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const printDocument = () => {
    html2canvas(inputRef.current).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, 0);
      pdf.save("download.pdf");
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <div className="mb5">
          <button onClick={printDocument}>Print</button>
        </div>
        <div id="divToPrint" ref={inputRef}>
            <Document/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean?
```I have issue data in the component show only in pdf and don`t need in webpage```
I suggest you should use another solution when converting HTML to pdf, Because with ```html2canvas```, It can not use for large HTML files (Pixel broken), and you will also get problems about the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You can write function export pdf in Document component and in App.js you can follow

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)
  ....
  const printDocument = () => {
   setClicked(true)
   }
  const handleCallBack = () => {
  setClicked(false)
  }
  ....
  <div style={{visibility: "hidden", overflow: "hidden", height: 0}}>
    <Document exportPDF={clicked} parentCallBack={handleCallBack}/>
   </div>

 
 
  **in Docment Component follow** 

   useEffect(() => {
   if(clicked){
       const printPDF = async () => {
      **code export pdf here**
     await pdf.save("download.pdf");
      parentCallBack(false)
    }
       printPDF()
    }},[clicked])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow or visit https://w3collective.com/react-component-pdf/

```js
const els = document.getElementsByClassName('App');
const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "px", "a4");
pdf.html(els[0]).then(() => {
   pdf.save("download.pdf");
});
```